# What if user remove question text after getting answer of the question

Tags: discussion

What if user remove question text after getting answer of the question.

Here is the question I have recently answer.

[PHP form submit with categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656319/php-form-submit-with-categories)

What should we do if user delete question text.

[Revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20656319/revisions)

Comment: I rolled back to the previous version after the user's first vandalism (http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20656319/4), but during the process of commenting to the OP, the question was deleted. I guess if the posting user has privileges that bypass review, they get to remove or vandalise posts more than others can. The question is currently deleted as I write this comment.

Comment: Thanks @JeremySmyth. Yeah I see you have rollback question to previous revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest the behavior I used in the past for such cases:

1. comment and make the asker notice that the question has gone ninja (ninja question-> a question that keeps changing content after any attempt to answer the current version. Much common when the question is "do my homework" and the asker keeps getting stuck).
2. Edit the question: if possible try to include both the original content and the new one, unless the new one does not relate at all with the original. In that case, suggest it to be posted as a different question
3. if anything else fails, <strike>use fire</strike> call for some moderator help. Use a custom flag, explain what is going on and they may provide some assistance.